# JPA and Threads in play framework

Tags: multithreading, jpa, playframework

I'm trying to create a multithreading server. The problem is that I get the following error:
*play.exceptions.JPAException: The JPA context is not initialized. JPA Entity Manager automatically start when one or more classes annotated with the @javax.persistence.Entity annotation are found in the application.*

What I'm trying to do is access the db from the new thread here's the code

```
package controllers;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import models.Ball;


public class MainLoop extends Thread {

@Override
public void run() {
    List<Ball> balls;
    new Ball(5,5,2,2,10,15);
    while (true){
        balls = Ball.all().fetch(); //Here throws an exception 

        for (Iterator iterator = balls.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Ball ball = (Ball) iterator.next();
            ball.applyForces();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't use plain thread, use jobs instead :

```
@OnApplicationStart 
public class MainLoop extends Job { 
       public void doJob() { 
               new BallJob().now(); 
       }
}
```

And BallJob :

```
public class BallJob extends Job {
public void doJob() {
    List<Ball> balls;
    new Ball(5,5,2,2,10,15);
    while (true){
        balls = Ball.all().fetch(); 
        for (Iterator iterator = balls.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Ball ball = (Ball) iterator.next();
            ball.applyForces();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's roughly 10 years old I realize, however, Job is a very generic thing. It would be better to specify the package for the Job object on an import. I don't know if you mean Spring Batch or something else.

Answer (score 6):

**Update**

This is neater than what's below:

```
JPAPlugin.startTx(false);
// Do your stuff
JPAPlugin.endTx(false);
```

**Had similar problem today.**

You have to create new `EntityManager` and transaction for each thread and set it in **JPA** class.

Play uses `ThreadLocal` to keep it's `EntityManager` in **JPA**, so it's null for your created thread. Unfortunately you cannot use helper methods in **JPA** to do it (they are package private) and you have to use `ThreadLocal` directly. Here's how you can do this:

```
class Runner extends Runnable {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         if (JPA.local.get() == null) {
             EntityManager em = JPA.newEntityManager();
             final JPA jpa = new JPA();
             jpa.entityManager = em;
             JPA.local.set(jpa);
         }

         JPA.em().getTransaction().begin();
         ... DO YOUR STUFF HERE ...
         JPA.em().getTransaction().commit();
     }
}
```

I use it with single thread executor from **java.util.concurrent** without any problems.

Comment: Update: You can remove all JPA stuff and replace it with JPAPlugin.startTx and JPAPlugin.closeTx.

Comment: How to work with JPA.local with play framework 1.4?, it changes completely

Comment: I like how simple the solution is. Unfortunately, if I use Spring Boot, I'm not sure there is a JPA object to refer to. Bonus points if you can provide a Spring Boot friendly answer as well :)

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing your thread is kicked off before Play has a chance to start the JPA Entity Manager.

If your Model class is annotated with @Entity, then the entity manager would have been created and your error would not appear.

So, you have a couple of options. Either,

1. You can create a PlayPlugin, with a lower priority than the Play standard onApplicationStart processes.
2. You can kickstart your thread from a bootstrap job. This will ensure that Play has had a chance to start up correctly before you start interacting with the server. To see more about bootstrap jobs, see http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1/jobs#concepts

Personally, I would go with option 2. It is better documented, and play plugins are meant more for extending the framework rather than changing the order of processing.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Runner extends Runnable {
     @Override
     public void run() {
        EntityManager em = JPA.newEntityManager();
        em.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);
        JPA jpa = new JPA();
        jpa.bindForCurrentThread(JPA.DEFAULT, em, false);

         em.getTransaction().begin();
        // ... DO YOUR STUFF HERE ...
         em.getTransaction().commit();
     }
}
```

Comment: Don't just give code as solution, give some explanation with it also.